# Hide the all after a specific number of occurences

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a div with the class of "list". In the list I have 24 p tags with the class of "listItem". I want to det "display: none;" on the sixth p.listItem in the div, I have tried with nth-child with no sucess, anyone that can help me?

Comment: Try `.list > .listItem:nth-child(n+6) { display: none; }`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing this?

```
.list .listItem:nth-child(6){

 display:none;

}
```